# I'm having a problem with my application on Azure Web App

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

So, I'm trying to publish my website on Azure Web App. I followed the steps that I saw in the Microsoft documentation for everything, but when I publish the application, it returns me a problem

[image]

And the logs:

[image]

I don't know if the problem is the line: 'Could not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'", so I tried to create this file manually, but it didn't work.

May someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I tried deploying the ASP .NET Core web app to the Azure App Service (Linux).

In your case, the error might be related to the startup command.

When I tried deploying the app to Azure App Service, it worked fine.

Open your Azure app service >> settings >> configuration >> General settings >> Startup Command.

Ensure your startup command is correct.

[image]

To check the deployed files in azure

1.Open you're Azure app service.

2. Search for Advanced Tools and click on it.
3. Afterward, click on Go.

[image]

[image]

4.Inside the wwwroot folder of the site, you can find your deployed files.

[image]

Here's the output:
[image]

I discovered that in your case, the error is due to an incorrect startup command, so I attempted to resolve it by intentionally misspelling the startup command.

In the picture below, you can see I mentioned the startup command as **dotnet Sdotnet.dll** instead of the correct one, **dotnet Sdotnet1.dll**.

[image]

I received the same error as you did.

[image]

This is the log stream

[image]

So verify the startup command specified for your  azure web app. Ensure that the main executable file of your ASP.NET Core application is accurately referenced.

Here's an example of a startup command :

```
dotnet YourApplicationName.dll
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer man! I will try to go by your recommendations and will come to send my feedback